# Building a ScreenShot Gallery with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, screenshot

I am currently in the process of trying to build a screenshot gallery. I have complete the first step which is to make it possible for the user to upload the image to a mysql database.

That is how the images for the gallery are supplied to the gallery script. Unfortunately, I have spent months perfecting my ability to get various things into a database, but not so much time on how to take them from the database and display in a user friendly format.

**Twitter Bootstrap Fluid Grid System**
Twitter Bootstrap utilizes a fluid grid system to display data. You don't have to use it, but it makes for a much better looking layout. Now the screenshot gallery needs to display rows of images and each row is 4 columns wide. Now here is the kicker, This is the structure for each row.

http://pastebin.com/HvBK5rTC

I need to generate that row over and over. But I need the images that populate it to cease at 4, echo the appropriate closing divs, echo the opening divs for another row, and the echo four more images out, ect, ect.

I don't have any code for this because I do not know where to start. I can supply anything that you need if you can just help me get started.

**Edit**
This is what I have come up with so far, but I do not know how to close the `<div class="row-fluid">` and open a new one.

http://pastebin.com/EADji2eh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty much there. `mysql_*` fn's are deprecated, you should use PDO etc.

You can do what you need by adding an outer loop for flow control, and using what you had already as an inner. The result array, it will automatically iterate through the result set for you without needing to keep track of offsets for limits etc.

**build_gallery_fn.php:**

```
function image_from_database() {
            // use a running counter for flow control of the outer loop
        $runningcount = 0;

        $r = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT logo AS `img` FROM NewsArticles WHERE logo IS NOT NULL AND logo !='';");

            //Get # of images in results to use as upper limit for outer loop
        $img_ct = mysql_num_rows($r);

        while ($runningcount <= $img_ct){

                    //rowcount reset to break content blocks
            $rowcount = 0;


            echo "<div class=\"row-fluid\">";

            $runningcount++;

                    while(($rowcount <= 3) && $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
            {
                    $rowcount++; 
                    $img = $row['img'];
                    echo '<div class="span2">';
                    echo "<span class='thumbnail'><img src='attachments/logos/$img'/> Photo # $runningcount of $img_ct</span>";
                    echo '</div>';
            }
            echo "</div>";

        }
}
```

**Output Holder:**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">The American Pacific Group ScreenShot Gallery</h1>
    <hr>

            <?php
                    echo image_from_database();
            ?>

</div>
```